# How does defining a MongoDB shard key influence the connectivity between my mongo(s/d)s?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am trying to test mongoDB sharding, but when following the basic steps in common tutorials, I am facing a CONNECT_ERROR issue that really doesn't make sense to me.

I use four machines for this test :

- One for the mongos process : let's call it "**GOS**"
- One for the config mongod : let's call it "**GOD**"
- Two for the storage (shards), that are on the same subnet, behind the same firewall : let's call them "**SH1**" and "**SH2**"

In real world, **GOS**, **GOD**, **SH1** and **SH2** are replaced by the matching IP addresses.

I assume that they are properly configured together, and they all can communicate.
They are all using port 49029 for legacy reasons.

Before playing with any data, on **GOS**,

```
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 3,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 3,
    "currentVersion" : 4,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("56446b3a8f521d8fad05f4c5")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "SH1:49029" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "SH2:49029" }
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
```

On **GOD**,

```
> use config
switched to db config
> db.shards.find()
{ "_id" : "shard0000", "host" : "SH1:49029" }
{ "_id" : "shard0001", "host" : "SH2:49029" }
```

Now consider the following sequence of instructions on **GOS**:

```
mongos> use test
switched to db test
mongos> db.createCollection("yolo")
{ "ok" : 1 }
mongos> db.yolo.insert({"test":"ok"})
mongos> db.yolo.count()
1
mongos> use admin
switched to db admin
mongos> db.adminCommand({"enableSharding" : "test"})
{ "ok" : 1 }
mongos> use test
switched to db test
mongos> db.yolo.count()
1
mongos> db.yolo.ensureIndex({"test":1})
mongos> db.yolo.count()
1
mongos> use admin
switched to db admin
mongos> db.adminCommand({"shardCollection":"test.yolo", key:{"test":1}})
{ "collectionsharded" : "test.yolo", "ok" : 1 }
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 3,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 3,
    "currentVersion" : 4,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("56446b3a8f521d8fad05f4c5")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "SH1:49029" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "SH2:49029" }
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "properties",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
    {  "_id" : "prorating_Ozon",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0001" }
        test.yolo
            shard key: { "test" : 1 }
            chunks:
                shard0001   1
            { "test" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "test" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0001 Timestamp(1, 0)

mongos> use test
switched to db test
mongos> db.yolo.count()
setShardVersion failed host: SH2:49029 { oldVersion: Timestamp 0|0, oldVersionEpoch: ObjectId(000000000000000000000000'), errmsg: exception: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for GOD:49029", code: 11002, ok: 0.0 }
```

The same error for each operation I tried to perform on this collection from **GOS** since I enabled sharding and specified the key.

Note that after inserting the data, I can open a mongo shell on **SH2** :

```
> use test
switched to db test
> db.yolo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("564493222b3e59c2861188f4"), "test" : "ok" }
```

It still works after **GOS** goes wrong.

What doesn't make much sense to me here is that it starts going wrong just after I start playing with shard keys. I think that the first insert going well eliminates the lead of firewall issues (I've had many, before).
I am not sure I really understand what the db.adminCommand({"shardCollection"[…]) implies, but I don't see how it could have any influence on connectivity between my entities.
I would really appreciate if someone with more experience could give me a clue of what is going on here.

---

Addendum, on **GOS**:

```
mongos> db.runCommand( { connPoolStats: 1 } )
{
    "hosts" : {
        "GOD:49029::0" : {
            "available" : 1,
            "created" : 1
        },
        "GOD:49029::30" : {
            "available" : 3,
            "created" : 3
        },
        "SH1:49029::0" : {
            "available" : 1,
            "created" : 2
        },
        "SH1:49029::30" : {
            "available" : 0,
            "created" : 2
        },
        "SH2:49029::0" : {
            "available" : 1,
            "created" : 2
        },
        "SH2:49029::30" : {
            "available" : 0,
            "created" : 2
        }
    },
    "replicaSets" : {

    },
    "createdByType" : {
        "master" : 12
    },
    "totalAvailable" : 6,
    "totalCreated" : 12,
    "numDBClientConnection" : 12,
    "numAScopedConnection" : 3,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: `GOD:49029` — is this the host that you have specified via the `--configdb` option when starting your `mongos`? Is this host reachable directly, by exactly this hostname and port, from `SH2`? Please verify this. Your shard servers *must* be able to connect to the config server.

Comment: Hi @DmytroShevchenko and thank you for your help. 
As I mentioned, in my actual situation, GOS, GOD, SH1 and SH2 are replaced by the matching IP addresses.
I have properly specified --configdb with the matching IP address when starting my mongos.
They are all ping-able from each other. I don't really know how to check that they can be reached directly with the given port, except by launching `mongo GOD:49029` from SH2, which works.

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/d1-sQe2_iUA you may find something useful in that discussion.

Comment: You asked how to see that everybody is reachable from every node. Check all mongos and mongod log-files for errors. If node cannot speak with other node, it will complain in the log file... As well,  it will tell when it managed to contact other nodes.